# Joining column of different rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If i have a dataframe and i want to merge ID column based on the Name column without deleting any row.
How would i do this?

Ex-

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| John | ABC |
| John | XYZ |
| Lucy | MNO |

I want to convert the above dataframe into the below one

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| John | ABC, XYZ |
| John | ABC, XYZ |
| Lucy | MNO |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `join`:

```
df['ID'] = df.groupby('Name')['ID'].transform(', '.join)
print (df)
   Name        ID
0  John  ABC, XYZ
1  John  ABC, XYZ
2  Lucy       MNO
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This was really  helpful. I have another question. Right now we are using GroupBy.transform  with name only. What if we have another column as "Organization"? Is there any way to do this based on Name and Organization instead of Name only?

Comment: @Krawly - Sure, use `df['ID'] = df.groupby(['Name','Organization'])['ID'].transform(', '.join)`

Comment: I am trying to perform the above operation on rows where Organization =="P" but can not figure it out. Can you help? I have only two values in organization ("P" or "O")

Comment: @Krawly - `m = df['Organization'] == 'P'` and then `df['ID'] = df[m].groupby('Name')['ID'].transform(', '.join)` - filter rows only with `P`

Comment: I tried this already and the ID with organization "O" are getting transformed into NaN in the final df.

Comment: @Krawly - Yes, it is expected. If no values then `NaN`

Comment: Yes but i have values in ID for Organization O as well
df= pd.DataFrame({"Name":["John", "John", "New", "New1"],"Org":["P", "P", "O", "O"], "ID":["ABC","XYZ", "MNO", "RST"]}) and these ids get tranformed into NaN.